# How to fold values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to fold values in db:

```
 update(ref(db, 'users/' + user.localId), {       
      countTrains: + countTrain, // here
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('Обновление бд');    
  })  
      .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
      });
```

But it doesn't work, after refresh value become to standart, please, help

Comment: What are `update`, `ref`, `db` and `countTrain` and what has this to do with React? Is '+ countTrain' supposed to be a command to the database? If so, should the code be `countTrains: '+ ' + countTrain`?